# UIScrollView with SubViews including ImageView, Label & Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm building an iOS app which requires the view to be displayed in the following format.

```
UIView  
UIScrollView
UIView (Content View)
UIImageView (20% height of View)
UILabel embedded in UIView (20% height or greater depending on label content)
UITableView (60% or greater depending on table content)
```

Above layout is build using storyboard. [image: see screenshot]

I see two scroll bar (one for UIScrollView and the other for UITableView). [image: see screenshot]

I tried disabling the scroll in UITableView hoping the UIScrollView would automatically scale but it truncates a chunk of tableview content. [image: see screenshot]

Is it possible to have a single scroll that could display the contents of Image, Label and TableView contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use scrollview as base because tableview have it's own scrollview.

You can put all this stuff directly on `UIView`.

If you want to scroll image and label up when user scroll then you can use `headerview` of `tableview`. you can configure `headerview` with image and label.

So, take tableView with full screen size and set headerview as required size (20% for imageview and 20 % for label in your case).

You can drag and drop `UIView` to tableview to set headerview. Your view hierarchy for tableview should be like below screenshot :

[image: Check screen shot]

Here view above tableview cell and below tabelview is your headerview.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: you're welcome... :) If you feeling it is helping then upvote the answer...:)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your tableview height constraint would solve this. If scrollview constraints are set proper

```
[tableview reloadData];
[tableHeightConstraint setConstant:tableview.contentsize.height]; 
[tableview setScrollEnabled:NO];
[tableview setBounces:NO];
```

height constraint for imageview and Tableviews are enough, Label height will be computed automatically